# PHP Arrays insert into MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

newbie with PHP and MySQL here. I've looked through other articles here to try and piece together the code that I'm after but struggling to get the content of two arrays inserted into two columns within a MySQL table.

The MySQL table is structured into three columns as follows -

```
|-------|-------|-------|
|   id  |  date | value |
|-------|-------|-------|
```

id is primary key set with auto_increment.
date is of date datatype.
value is of decimal(5,2) datatype.

I have two PHP arrays `$dates` and `$values` which contain the following -

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($dates); echo '</pre>';
Array
(
    [0] => 2015
    [1] => 2014
    [2] => 2013
    [3] => 2012
    [4] => 2011
    [5] => 2010
    [6] => 2009
    [7] => 2008
    [8] => 2007
    [9] => 2006
    [10] => 2005
    [11] => 2004
    [12] => 2003
    [13] => 2002
    [14] => 2001
    [15] => 2000
    [16] => 1999
    [17] => 1998
    [18] => 1997
    [19] => 1996
    [20] => 1995
    [21] => 1994
    [22] => 1993
    [23] => 1992
    [24] => 1991
    [25] => 1990
    [26] => 1989
    [27] => 1988
    [28] => 1987
)

echo '<pre>'; print_r($values); echo '</pre>';
Array
(
    [0] => 52.32
    [1] => 98.97
    [2] => 108.56
    [3] => 111.63
    [4] => 111.26
    [5] => 79.61
    [6] => 61.74
    [7] => 96.94
    [8] => 72.44
    [9] => 65.16
    [10] => 54.57
    [11] => 38.26
    [12] => 28.85
    [13] => 24.99
    [14] => 24.46
    [15] => 28.66
    [16] => 17.9
    [17] => 12.76
    [18] => 19.11
    [19] => 20.64
    [20] => 17.02
    [21] => 15.86
    [22] => 17.01
    [23] => 19.32
    [24] => 20.04
    [25] => 23.76
    [26] => 18.23
    [27] => 14.91
    [28] => 18.53
)
```

I've serialized the data into two new variables prior to my insert query -

```
$mydates = serialize($dates);
$myvalues = serialize($values);
```

My insert statement is then as follows -

```
$query = "INSERT INTO eia(date,value) VALUES ('$mydates','$myvalues')";
```

with some error handling -

```
if ($conn->query($query)) {
   $msg = ...Sucessfully Entered!
} else {
    $msg = ...Error Entering!
}
if (isset($msg)){
  echo $msg;
}
if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO eia(date,value) VALUES ('$mydates','$myvalues')")) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
}
```

Then finally close the connection -

```
mysqli_close($conn);
```

When this runs I receive the 'Successfully Entered' message but on inspecting the MySQL table I just get two rows with the following -

```
id | date | value
1  |{null}| 0.00
2  |{null}| 0.00
```

Any ideas how I can get the contents of these arrays added into each column i.e.

```
id | date | value
1  | 2015 | 52.32
2  | 2014 | 98.97
...
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _“I've serialized the data into two new variables”_ – that makes absolutely no sense here whatsoever. And it is also the reason you get NULL/0.00 in your new record, because by serializing those arrays your are creating _strings_ that match neither the format of your date or your decimal column.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the feedback. I see the error I've made here, which created the resulting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need serialize here

```
if ($conn->query($sql)) {
   $msg = ...Sucessfully Entered!
} else {
    $msg = ...Error Entering!
}
if (isset($msg)){
  echo $msg;
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO eia_brent(eiaDate,eiaValue) VALUES';
foreach ($dates as $index => $date) {
    $sql .= "($date, ".$values[$index]."),";
}
$sql = trim($sql,',');

if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
}
```

Comment: Good attempt but OP said dates is one array and values is another array

Comment: @e4c5 Yup but both have same indexes as given in the question, I have iterated $dates and used the value present in $values at that same index by $values[$key]. Correct if something wrong

Comment: I see what you mean. Was thrown off by the fact the $key is often used (mere convention) when dealing with associative arrays. So your answer is indeed correct but it's variable naming ($value and $values also confusing) that was a red herring.

Comment: @e4c5 changed that

Comment: @SatyapalSharma thank you. This code worked, added two semicolons (one in the foreach loop and one for the trim statement) and changed $query to $sql, I now have the data from both arrays in both columns. I changed the datatype of date to int as well. Is it possible to empty the table prior to each run so that any new data in the array is added to the table? i.e. DELETE FROM eia or TRUNCATE?

Comment: I've added a TRUNCATE query prior to the insert query to empty the table.

Comment: @CRC Yup you should use Truncate <table name> at top of your script. And if it's working correctly mark it as accepted answer so that other don't have to search for it.

Comment: @CRC Always use truncate over delete (if possible) as it is much faster. As delete navigates through the table and delete each row while truncate just drop the table and create it again

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are running same query two times:

```
if ($conn->query($query)) {
```

and

```
if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO eia_brent(eiaDate,eiaValue) VALUES ('$mydates','$myvalues')")) {
```

---

You get `null` and `0.00` because you try to insert serialized information into single cell.

Multiple insert query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO eia_brent(eiaDate, eiaValues)
VALUES ('myDate1', 'myValue1'), ('myDate2', 'myValue2'), ('myDate3', 'myValue3'), [...]
```

You can loop your array and create query:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO eia_brent(eiaDate, eiaValues) VALUES';
$values = [];

foreach ($dates as $i => $date) {
    $values[] = "('{$date}', '{$values[$i]}')"; // validate your input to database first!
}

$query .= implode(', ', $values);

$conn->query($query);
```

Comment: Although you will have to convert $values[$i] into proper date formate upon inserting or you will get 0000-00-00 as values

Comment: You should either use (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE({$values[$i]},'%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d')) or change column type to int

Comment: @Justinas. Thank you. I tried the code above, but nothing inserted into the table? I adjusted the date column datatype to int.

Answer (score 0):

Date datatype will accept date in YYYY-MM-DD format, between 1000-01-01 and 9999-12-31. For example, December 30th, 1973 would be stored as 1973-12-30.If you are very particular about storing only the year it is better to use int datatype

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense, I've adjusted the datatype to INT instead of a date type.